# How to delete mdf file in use but not attached?

Tags: sql-server

I have a mdf file that is not attached but when I try to delete it Windows Explorer fails due to the file being in use. SQL Manager also says it's in use when I try to attach the MDF so that I can delete it. Is there a way to kill the connection and delete the file without stopping the SQL service?  Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you might have more than one instance of SQL Server installed, or the database is attached as a name that is not obvious from the file name.

Comment: You need to find out what process has a handle to the file.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: I have looked and there is only one instance of sql 2014 installed on the box.

Comment: I have tried using process explorer and can't figure out how to use it to find what is using the db. Searching for a db name doesn't result in anything. Even searching for functioning db's doesn't result in anything.I have tried searching and drag and drop on the bulls eye icon.

Comment: Strange thing is if I create a backup that database is in the selection list for databases.

Comment: Does it return any result: `SELECT DB_NAME(database_id), name, physical_name FROM sys.master_files WHERE physical_name LIKE '%YourFileName%';`?
Also, to see if sql server is using the file you can download [Handle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) and, on an Admin elevated CMD prompt, run `handle -p sqlservr`

Comment: One more thing, when Aaron said there could be another SQL Server using the file, it didn't need to be on the same box. Maybe some other server accessing the file. I think you can check it by `RUN > compmgmt.msc > Computer Management > System Tools > Shared Folders > Open Files`

Comment: I ran the query and it found both the mdf and ldf files. Handle also found them under sql. The db files are there but I can't attach (fails - process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) and if I try to delete the files in Win Explorer it also says it's in use.  Is my only option to shut down sqlservice and delete the files? Is this safe to do? Will it leave an orphaned db?

Comment: Should I try setting it to Single_User and then delete the files?

Comment: Now you know what database is using the file. Yes, If you wish to delete the .mdf file along with other files associated with that database, set it to SINGLE_USER and execute a  DROP database, that way SQL Server will eliminate all the files at once and no reference will be left on the instance. Only issue the DROP if you intend to delete **all** the files associated with that database (not only the first .mdf you mentioned). If that works as you expected, I shall write a proper answer. One  more thing: you should mark our user name (like @PBK) for us to get notified of you reply.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the database (returned by the query in sys.master_files) Offline with

```
Alter database [YourDB] set offline;
```

If the database is still seen in the dmv, it may still be possible to set it as offline (and then you'll be able to delete the file).

But if you want to delete the file, you could also just try to drop the database

```
Drop database [YourDB];
```